# Can't append table row to table Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append a table row to a table once the submit button is clicked, but it won't append.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
<form id="sizePicker">
    Grid Height:
    <input type="number" id="input_height" name="height" min="1" value="1">
    Grid Width:
    <input type="number" id="input_width" name="width" min="1" value="1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<h2>Pick A Color</h2>
<input type="color" id="colorPicker">

<h2>Design Canvas</h2>
<table>
<table>

<script src="designs.js"></script>
```

Here is my JS file:

```
function makeGrid() {    
    $('#sizePicker').on('submit', function( evt ) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
    });
}
(function () { 
  makeGrid();
 }());
```

Comment: you have `<table><table>` so you don´t close your tag

Comment: How you invoke `makeGrid()` ?

Comment: Works fine for me if you fix the typo in your table tags https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3yr817u0/

Comment: It works now. It was appending it to the page. The problem was with my CSS. thank you!